# Detect if screen brightness adjustment is set to automatic

Tags: ios, uiscreen

I would like to get something like a Boolean to tell if the user set the Auto-Brightness feature of the iPhone on/off. Is this even possible?

I thought it would be explained somewhere [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/currentMode) - in UIScreen - currentMode but it seems that it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think its possible.

Apple's official public APIs do not allow an iOS app to access General settings in the Settings app. So it is not possible to change/ detect the toggle button inside the settings app.

and ofcourse we can set brightness for our app like below.

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:X]` ( X is a float value between 0.0 - 1.0)